# Redux: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: [object Promise])

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, use-effect

I'm making this application with react, redux and axios where one component shows a full list of addresses and the next shows one selected address. The address listing component work fine but there's something wrong with the single view component which returns the following error:

[image]

somewhere in the redux chain involving changeSelected->address there is a promise being sent instead of the promised results. I'm having a hard time pinpointing this as I've used a similar structure for the multi address view fetchAddresses -> addresses which works fine.

here's my react component

```
const Card = async (props) => {
    const { changeSelected,address } = props
    console.log(address)

    useEffect(() => {
            changeSelected(1);
    },[changeSelected(1)])

    if (!address){
        return <h1>No results</h1>
    } else {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
              <CssBaseline />
              <Container maxWidth="sm">
                <Typography component="div" style={{ backgroundColor: '#cfe8fc', height: '100vh' }} >   
                    <Typography variant="h6" >{address.body}</Typography>
                </Typography>
              </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
          );
    }

}

Card.propTypes = {
    changeSelected: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    address: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    address: state.address.address,

})


export default connect(mapStateToProps, {changeSelected})(Card)
```

here is my dispatched action

```
export const changeSelected = (postData) => dispatch => {
    console.log(postData)
    axios.get(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${postData}`)
        .then(addresses => {
            console.log(addresses)
            dispatch({
            type: CHANGE_SELECTED,
            payload: addresses.data
        })}).catch(err => {
            dispatch({
                //if there's an error, send the user a card saying so
                type: CHANGE_SELECTED,
                payload: [{id:0,nickName:'error',content:'please contact cutomer service at 010-314-1150'}]
            })
            console.log(err)
        })
}
```

and here is my reducer

```
//create initial state
const initialState = {
    addresses: [],
    address:{}
}


export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case FETCH_ADDRESSES:
            return{
                ...state,
                addresses: action.payload
            }
        case CHANGE_SELECTED:
            return{
                address: action.payload
            }
        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

the response is making it to the reducer but the error message is being called before a promise is returned.

Comment: what is `address.body` type?

Comment: it should be a string

Comment: "should", can you console.log out for sure? or what is the object it is referring too?

Comment: in theory it should be returned from the address field in the state, which is initially an empty object but should be filled with the addresses.data object gathered from axios which is {userid:[int],id:[int],body:[string]} if I console.log the addresses.data in the reducer it's making in there, but if I console.log the address in the component then I just get an empty object before everything breaks

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the problem was designating my react component (Card) as "async". got rid of that and it worked fine.